# How to correctly use ES6 "export default" with CommonJS "require"?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, commonjs, es6-module-loader

I've been working through [Webpack tutorial](http://blog.madewithlove.be/post/webpack-your-bags/). In one of the sections, it gives the code example that contains one line of essence to this question:

```js
export default class Button { /* class code here */ }
```

In the next section of said tutorial, titled "Code splitting", the class defined above is loaded on demand, like this:

```js
require.ensure([], () => {
    const Button = require("./Components/Button");
    const button = new Button("google.com");
    // ...
});
```

Unfortunately, this code throws an exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Button is not a function
```

Now, I know that the *right* way to include ES6 module would be to simply `import Button from './Components/Button';` at the top of the file, but using a construct like that anywhere else in the file makes babel a sad panda:

```
SyntaxError: index.js: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level
```

After some fiddling with previous (`require.ensure()`) example above, I realized that ES6 `export default` syntax exports an object that has property named `default`, which contains my code (the `Button` function).

I did fix the broken code example by appending `.default` after require call, like this:

```js
const Button = require("./Components/Button").default;
```

...but I think it looks a bit clumsy and it is error-prone (I'd have to know which module uses ES6 syntax, and which uses good old `module.exports`).

Which brings me to my question: **what is the right way to import ES6 code from code that uses CommonJS syntax?**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To use `export default` with Babel, you can do 1 of the following:

1. `require("myStuff").default`
2. `npm install babel-plugin-add-module-exports --save-dev`

Or 3:

```
//myStuff.js
var thingToExport = {};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports["default"] = thingToExport;
```

Comment: the fastest way to find out all details is using ```babel-cli``` to transpile one file and see what the result is. The defineProperty-thing is just needed... - so thanks for pointing all this out

Answer (score -1):

If someone using the gulp + browserify + babelify to bundle js using in client-end.

Try following code **[gulpfile.js]**:

```
browserify({
  entries: "./ui/qiyun-ui/javascripts/qiyun-ui.src.js",
  standalone: "qyUI" // To UMD
})
.transform(babelify, {
  presets: ["env"],
  plugins: ["add-module-exports"] // export default {} => module.exports = exports['default'];
})
.bundle()
```

Don't forget to install this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-module-exports