# How does ES6 import / export play along with CommonJS exports / require

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, commonjs

Sometimes you want to combine these syntaxes, most often when `import`ing something that uses the commonjs syntax. Some cases were already discussed for example here:

[How to correctly use ES6 "export default" with CommonJS "require"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35971042/how-to-correctly-use-es6-export-default-with-commonjs-require)

but there surely are more situations that can occur!

Comment: This depends on the module syntax transpiler and the module loader or bundler that you use. You should be able to find everything in their docs.

Answer (score 3):

As @Bergi and @Mike pointed in the comments, it is up to the transpiler (most commonly Babel), how it copes with ES6 import / export. Few examples, what you'll got with Babel (with its standard plugins):

## CommonJS export, ES6 import

```
module.exports = 1    // a.js
import one from './a' // b.js
// one === 1

module.exports = {one: 1}  // a.js
import obj from './a'      // b.js
// obj is {one: 1}

import * as obj from './a' // b.js
// obj.one === 1 ; however, check out the 'funky stuff' below

import {one} from './a'    // b.js
// one === 1
```

## ES6 export, CommonJS require

```
export default 1 // a.js
const one = require('./a').default
// one === 1

export const one = 1
const one = require('./a').one
// one === 1
```

## Funky stuff

```
module.exports = 1          // a.js
import * as obj from './a'  // b.js
// obj is {default: 1}

module.exports = {one: 1}   // a.js
import * as obj from './a'  // b.js
// obj is {one: 1, default: {one: 1}}
```

Comment: Where is this spec? I'm 99% sure that it's completely up to the transpiler.

Comment: @MikeC: You're right, there is no spec for how those two syntaxes should interoperate. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Bergi: No, there isn't, my mistake.