# Difference between export const foo, export default foo and module.exports = foo

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am really confused about:

1. `export const foo`
2. `export default foo`
3. `module.exports = foo;`

I know these are very basic but could someone please differentiate and explain these to me. I really want to understand.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294870/module-exports-vs-export-default-in-node-js-and-es6

Comment: I'm also wondering about `export const WHATEVER = ({ aVar }) => {   .. some code .. }`   Can't find an example of that anywhere.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Let take each of these one by one.

**export const**

```
 export const foo
```

This is ES6 export syntax for a named export.  You can have many named exports.  It says that you want to export the value of the variable `foo` and you are also declaring that symbol to be `const` in this module.

You can't actually use `export const foo` all by itself just like you can use `const foo;` all by itself.  Instead, you would have to assign something to it:

```
export const foo = 12;
```

The `const` applies only to within the module itself.  It does not affect what someone can do with the value once they've imported the value from the module on the other end because at the other end (where its imported), it's value is copied into another variable.  If that other variable is created with the import statement, then it is automatically `const` on the import side (you cannot assign to it) no matter what it was declared on the export side.

This could be imported as either of these:

```
import {foo as localFoo} from 'lib';
import {foo} from 'lib';
```

The first imports the `foo` property of the module into a `localFoo` named variable.
The second imports the `foo` property of the module into a `foo` named variable.

---

**export default**

```
export default foo
```

This is also ES6 syntax and says that you also want to export the value of the variable `foo` and you want that to be the `default` export value so if someone imports just the module and not any properties of the module, this is the variable they will get.  You can only have one `default` export per module.

Internally, the default export is really just a named export with the special name `default` assigned:

```
import localVar from 'myLib';
```

This will get the `default` export from myLib and assign it's value to a locally declared variable named `localVar`.  The above is a shorthand for this:

```
import { default as localVar } from 'lib';
```

So, the `default` export just allows you to have a shortcut import for one particular export.  The ES6 import/export syntax was designed to make the syntax as brief as possible for the default import/export.  But, for obvious reasons, there is only one default property per module.

---

**module.exports**

```
// inside of myModule
module.exports = foo;
```

This is node.js syntax for exporting the value of the variable `foo` and you're exporting it at the top level.  When someone uses this module:

```
let x = require('myModule');
console.log(x);    //  will show the value of `foo` from the previous module
```

This is not ES6 syntax, but is regular ES5-compatible syntax using the `module.exports` and `require()` infrastructure built into node.js.

Answer (score 5):

> The [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) statement is used to export functions, objects or primitives from a given file (or module).

---

**Named Exports**
This is a named export in ES6 javascript

```
export const foo
```

which is imported like:

```
import { foo } from 'path'
```

---

**Default Export**
This is a default export (This can be imported using any name)

```
export default foo
```

which is imported like so:

```
import bar from 'path'
```

---

This is commonjs export which is used in nodejs programs.

module.exports = foo;

which is imported like:

```
var foo = require('path')
```

---

For [more](http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/babel-commonjs.html) details

Answer (score 0):

export const foo : exports constants (ES6)
export default foo : exports object (ES6)

Above statements are ECMA Script 2015 (aka ES6) implementation.

In an normal ES6 JS file one can export any object(variable) or constants. Pls note that you cannot change constant reference, though internal structure can be modified(weird).

In ES6 one can have multiple exports in module(script file). which can be added in calling script as

```
import {Obj1, Obj2} from module_file
```

coming to export default, One can have only one export default in module. and while importing when exact names are not defined default is been picked up.

module.exports = foo; is older implementation and it is same as export default. except it is imported with require statement instead of import

for more    refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export