# Why can't I use the import syntax to import a coffeescript file from typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, coffeescript

I have a typescript file and I am importing various typescript files as follows:

```
import ThingAMajig from '../../../libs/stuffs/ThingAMajig'; // a typescript file
```

But I have to import my coffeescript files in this way:

```
const CoolThing = require('../../../libs/coolDir/CoolThing');
```

When I try to use the import syntax, I get an error `error TS2307: Cannot find module`.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294870/module-exports-vs-export-default-in-node-js-and-es6

Answer (score 0):

I can half answer this..I'm know a bit about babel, webpack and typescript.
You'd need to investigate coffee-loader a bit more.
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/coffee-loader

I'm used to using brew on a Mac.
You can probably sudo npm install webpack too,
or do it as administrator on Windows machine.

- run npm init first inside new empty project folder
- npm install -g webpack
- brew install webpack
- npm install --save-dev babel-loader

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports =  {
    entry: '/scripts.js'
    output: {filename 'bundle.js'}
    module: {
       loaders: [
        {test: /\.js?/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules}
    ]
    }
}
```

- webpack -> bundle.js
- add bundle.js to index.html within script tag
- You probably need to add the loaders for your coffee script in the webpack.config.js