# Difference between destructing export default and module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I've been struggling to destruct my mongo object in another file, my object structure is like below.

```
  const env = {
       project: 'CRIBBBLE BACKEND',
       url: 'localhost',
       api: {
         url: 'https://api.dribbble.com/v1/',
       },
       port: parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000,
       mongo: database,
};

 export default env;
```

But when I'm trying to `import` the `mongo` object in another `js` file like this `{ mongo } from 'config'` the returned value is `undefined`. 
But if I change the export default value to `module.exports` it works as its expected.

So, I'm just wondering what is the difference between `module.exports` and `export default`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [module.exports vs. export default in Node.js and ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294870/module-exports-vs-export-default-in-node-js-and-es6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you export using `export default foo` the whole exported `foo` is available using `{default: foo}` after import. That's why you cannot access properties you want. Try to import as: `import * as bar from './foo'` and explore the `bar` using `console.log(bar)` to see what's happening underneath. Also for more info have a look: [es6 module exports](http://2ality.com/2015/07/es6-module-exports.html) on 2ality.com

Answer (score 3):

`module.exports` is a NodeJS ([**CommonJS**](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html)) style of importing and exporting from different files. `import/export` is `ES6` feature of doing the same thing.

If you `export defualt` you need to import it like `import env from 'location'`(Look I emit the `{}` part) and then access the `mongo` via `env.mongo`. You can't just get the `mongo` object directly.

Comment: So, what is the difference in my case?

Comment: Ok but I still do not understand why I'm not able to destruct the returned object with `export default`