# Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, ecmascript-5

I want to integrate this library in my vue project:
https://github.com/ZemezPlugins/rd-navbar

But I got very strange errors, when I include it with a require I get the following error: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#'.

So I thought im going to add it in a separate file and add it with an import, but then I get this.initialize is not a function.

Is it due imports? If so, how can I make this library work? I have included it underneath.

```
/**
 * @module       RD Navbar
 * @author       Evgeniy Gusarov
 * @version      2.2.5
 */
(function() {
  var isTouch;

  isTouch = "ontouchstart" in window;

  (function($, document, window) {

    /**
     * Creates a RDNavbar.
     * @class RDNavbar.
     * @public
     * @param {HTMLElement} element - The element to create the RDNavbar for.
     * @param {Object} [options] - The options
     */
    var RDNavbar;
    RDNavbar = (function() {

      /**
       * Default options for RDNavbar.
   * @protected
   */
  RDNavbar.prototype.Defaults = {
    layout: 'rd-navbar-static',
    deviceLayout: 'rd-navbar-fixed',
    focusOnHover: true,
    focusOnHoverTimeout: 800,
    linkedElements: ["html"],
    domAppend: true,
    stickUp: true,
    stickUpClone: true,
    stickUpOffset: '100%',
    anchorNav: true,
    anchorNavSpeed: 400,
    anchorNavOffset: 0,
    anchorNavEasing: 'swing',
    autoHeight: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        layout: "rd-navbar-fixed",
        deviceLayout: "rd-navbar-fixed",
        focusOnHover: false,
        stickUp: false
      },
      992: {
        layout: "rd-navbar-static",
        deviceLayout: "rd-navbar-static",
        focusOnHover: true,
        stickUp: true
      }
    },
    callbacks: {
      onToggleSwitch: false,
      onToggleClose: false,
      onDomAppend: false,
      onDropdownOver: false,
      onDropdownOut: false,
      onDropdownToggle: false,
      onDropdownClose: false,
      onStuck: false,
      onUnstuck: false,
      onAnchorChange: false
    }
  };

  function RDNavbar(element, options) {

    /**
     * Current options set
     * @public
     */
    this.options = $.extend(true, {}, this.Defaults, options);

    /**
     * Plugin element
     * @public
     */
    this.$element = $(element);

    /**
     * Plugin element clone
     * @public
     */
    this.$clone = null;

    /**
     * Additional references
     * @public
     */
    this.$win = $(window);
    this.$doc = $(document);
    this.currentLayout = this.options.layout;
    this.loaded = false;
    this.focusOnHover = this.options.focusOnHover;
    this.focusTimer = false;
    this.cloneTimer = false;
    this.isStuck = false;
    this.initialize();
  }


  /**
   * Initializes the RDNavbar.
   * @protected
   */

  RDNavbar.prototype.initialize = function() {
    var ctx;
    ctx = this;
    ctx.$element.addClass("rd-navbar").addClass(ctx.options.layout);
    if (isTouch) {
      ctx.$element.addClass("rd-navbar--is-touch");
    }
    if (ctx.options.domAppend) {
      ctx.createNav(ctx);
    }
    if (ctx.options.stickUpClone) {
      ctx.createClone(ctx);
    }
    ctx.$element.addClass('rd-navbar-original');
    ctx.addAdditionalClassToToggles('.rd-navbar-original', 'toggle-original', 'toggle-original-elements');
    ctx.applyHandlers(ctx);
    ctx.offset = ctx.$element.offset().top;
    ctx.height = ctx.$element.outerHeight();
    ctx.loaded = true;
    return ctx;
  };


  /**
   * Changes {ctx.$element} layout basing on screen resolution
   * @protected
   */

  RDNavbar.prototype.resize = function(ctx, e) {
    var targetElement, targetLayout;
    targetLayout = isTouch ? ctx.getOption('deviceLayout') : ctx.getOption('layout');
    targetElement = ctx.$element.add(ctx.$clone);
    if (targetLayout !== ctx.currentLayout || !ctx.loaded) {
      ctx.switchClass(targetElement, ctx.currentLayout, targetLayout);
      if (ctx.options.linkedElements != null) {
        $.grep(ctx.options.linkedElements, function(link, index) {
          return ctx.switchClass(link, ctx.currentLayout + '-linked', targetLayout + '-linked');
        });
      }
      ctx.currentLayout = targetLayout;
    }
    ctx.focusOnHover = ctx.getOption('focusOnHover');
    return ctx;
  };


  /**
   * Toggles bar stickup on scroll
   * @protected
   */

  RDNavbar.prototype.stickUp = function(ctx, e) {
    var scrollTop, stickUp, stickUpOffset, targetElement, threshold;
    stickUp = ctx.getOption("stickUp");
    if ($('html').hasClass('ios') || ctx.$element.hasClass('rd-navbar-fixed')) {
      stickUp = false;
    }
    scrollTop = ctx.$doc.scrollTop();
    targetElement = ctx.$clone != null ? ctx.$clone : ctx.$element;
    stickUpOffset = ctx.getOption('stickUpOffset');
    threshold = (typeof stickUpOffset === 'string' ? (stickUpOffset.indexOf('%') > 0 ? parseFloat(stickUpOffset) * ctx.height / 100 : parseFloat(stickUpOffset)) : stickUpOffset);
    if (stickUp) {
      if ((scrollTop >= threshold && !ctx.isStuck) || (scrollTop < threshold && ctx.isStuck)) {
        ctx.$element.add(ctx.$clone).find('[data-rd-navbar-toggle]').each(function() {
          $.proxy(ctx.closeToggle, this)(ctx, false);
        }).end().find('.rd-navbar-submenu').removeClass('opened').removeClass('focus');
        if (scrollTop >= threshold && !ctx.isStuck && !ctx.$element.hasClass('rd-navbar-fixed')) {
          if (ctx.options.callbacks.onStuck) {
            ctx.options.callbacks.onStuck.call(ctx);
          }


          setTimeout(function(){
            if (e.type === 'resize') {
              ctx.switchClass(targetElement, '', 'rd-navbar--is-stuck');
            } else {
              targetElement.addClass('rd-navbar--is-stuck');
            }
            ctx.isStuck = true;
          }, navigator.platform.match(/(Mac)/i) ? 10 : 0);

        } else {
          if (e.type === 'resize') {
            ctx.switchClass(targetElement, 'rd-navbar--is-stuck', '');
          } else {
            targetElement.removeClass('rd-navbar--is-stuck').one('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd', $.proxy(ctx.resizeWrap, ctx, e));
          }
          ctx.isStuck = false;
          if (ctx.options.callbacks.onUnstuck) {
            ctx.options.callbacks.onUnstuck.call(ctx);
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      ctx.$element.find('.rd-navbar-submenu').removeClass('opened').removeClass('focus');
      if (ctx.isStuck) {
        ctx.switchClass(targetElement, 'rd-navbar--is-stuck', '');
        ctx.isStuck = false;
        ctx.resizeWrap(e);
      }
    }
    return ctx;
  };


  /**
   * Resizes an external wrap of navbar
   * @protected
   */

  RDNavbar.prototype.resizeWrap = function(e) {
    var $wrap, ctx;
    ctx = this;
    if ((ctx.$clone == null) && !ctx.isStuck) {
      $wrap = ctx.$element.parent();
      if (!ctx.getOption('autoHeight')) {
        $wrap.css('height', 'auto');
        return;
      }
      ctx.height = ctx.$element.outerHeight();
      if (e.type === 'resize') {
        $wrap.addClass('rd-navbar--no-transition').css('height', ctx.height);
        $wrap[0].offsetHeight;
        return $wrap.removeClass('rd-navbar--no-transition');
      } else {
        return $wrap.css('height', ctx.height);
      }
    }
  };


  /**
   * Creates additional DOM for navigation functionality
   * @protected
   */

  RDNavbar.prototype.createNav = function(ctx) {
    ctx.$element.find('.rd-navbar-dropdown, .rd-navbar-megamenu').each(function() {
      var $this, rect;
      $this = $(this);
      rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
      if ($this.hasClass('rd-navbar-megamenu')) {
        return $this.parent().addClass('rd-navbar--has-megamenu');
      } else {
        return $this.parent().addClass('rd-navbar--has-dropdown');
      }
    }).parents("li").addClass("rd-navbar-submenu");
    $('<span class="rd-navbar-submenu-toggle"></span>').insertAfter('.rd-navbar-nav li.rd-navbar-submenu > a');
    if (ctx.options.callbacks.onDomAppend) {
      ctx.options.callbacks.onDomAppend.call(this);
    }
    return ctx;
  };


      /**
       * Creates navbar clone to stick up
       * @protected
       */

      RDNavbar.prototype.createClone = function(ctx) {
        ctx.$clone = ctx.$element.clone().insertAfter(ctx.$element).addClass('rd-navbar--is-clone');
        ctx.addAdditionalClassToToggles('.rd-navbar--is-clone', 'toggle-cloned', 'toggle-cloned-elements');
        return ctx;
      };


      /**
       * Closes all toggles on outside click of each item
       * @protected
       */

      RDNavbar.prototype.closeToggle = function(ctx, e) {
        var $items, $target, additionalToggleElClass, additionalToogleClass, collapse, linkedElements, needClose;
        $target = $(e.target);
        collapse = false;
        linkedElements = this.getAttribute('data-rd-navbar-toggle');
        if (ctx.options.stickUpClone && ctx.isStuck) {
          additionalToogleClass = '.toggle-cloned';
          additionalToggleElClass = '.toggle-cloned-elements';
          needClose = !$target.hasClass('toggle-cloned');
        } else {
          additionalToogleClass = '.toggle-original';
          additionalToggleElClass = '.toggle-original-elements';
          needClose = !$target.hasClass('toggle-original');
        }
        if (e.target !== this && !$target.parents(additionalToogleClass + '[data-rd-navbar-toggle]').length && !$target.parents(additionalToggleElClass).length && linkedElements && needClose) {
          $items = $(this).parents('body').find(linkedElements).add($(this).parents('.rd-navbar')[0]);
          $items.each(function() {
            if (!collapse) {
              return collapse = (e.target === this || $.contains(this, e.target)) === true;
            }
          });
          if (!collapse) {
            $items.add(this).removeClass('active');
            if (ctx.options.callbacks.onToggleClose) {
              ctx.options.callbacks.onToggleClose.call(this, ctx);
            }
          }
        }
        return this;
      };


      /**
       * Switches toggle
       * @protected
       */

      RDNavbar.prototype.switchToggle = function(ctx, e) {
        var additionalToggleElClass, linkedElements, navbarClass;
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).hasClass('toggle-cloned')) {
          navbarClass = '.rd-navbar--is-clone';
          additionalToggleElClass = '.toggle-cloned-elements';
        } else {
          navbarClass = '.rd-navbar-original';
          additionalToggleElClass = '.toggle-original-elements';
        }
        if (linkedElements = this.getAttribute('data-rd-navbar-toggle')) {
          $(navbarClass + ' [data-rd-navbar-toggle]').not(this).each(function() {
            var deactivateElements;
            if (deactivateElements = this.getAttribute('data-rd-navbar-toggle')) {
              return $(this).parents('body').find(navbarClass + ' ' + deactivateElements + additionalToggleElClass).add(this).add($.inArray('.rd-navbar', deactivateElements.split(/\s*,\s*/i)) > -1 ? $(this).parents('body')[0] : false).removeClass('active');
            }
          });
          $(this).parents('body').find(navbarClass + ' ' + linkedElements + additionalToggleElClass).add(this).add($.inArray('.rd-navbar', linkedElements.split(/\s*,\s*/i)) > -1 ? $(this).parents('.rd-navbar')[0] : false).toggleClass('active');
        }
        if (ctx.options.callbacks.onToggleSwitch) {
          ctx.options.callbacks.onToggleSwitch.call(this, ctx);
        }
        return this;
      };


      /**
       * Triggers submenu popup to be shown on mouseover
       * @protected
       */

      RDNavbar.prototype.dropdownOver = function(ctx, timer) {
        var $this;
        if (ctx.focusOnHover) {
          $this = $(this);
          clearTimeout(timer);
          if (ctx.options.callbacks.onDropdownOver) {
            if (!ctx.options.callbacks.onDropdownOver.call(this, ctx)){
              return this;
            }
          }

          $this.addClass('focus').siblings().removeClass('opened').each(ctx.dropdownUnfocus);
        }
        return this;
      };


      /**
       * Triggers submenu popup to be shown on mouseover
       * @protected
       */

      RDNavbar.prototype.dropdownTouch = function(ctx, timer) {
        var $this, hasFocus;
        $this = $(this);
        clearTimeout(timer);
        if (ctx.focusOnHover) {
          hasFocus = false;
          if ($this.hasClass('focus')) {
            hasFocus = true;
          }
          if (!hasFocus) {
            $this.addClass('focus').siblings().removeClass('opened').each(ctx.dropdownUnfocus);
            return false;
          }
          if (ctx.options.callbacks.onDropdownOver) {
            ctx.options.callbacks.onDropdownOver.call(this, ctx);
          }
        }
        return this;
      };


      /**
       * Triggers submenu popop to be hidden on mouseout
       * @protected
       */

      RDNavbar.prototype.dropdownOut = function(ctx, timer) {
        var $this;
        if (ctx.focusOnHover) {
          $this = $(this);
          $this.one('mouseenter.navbar', function() {
            return clearTimeout(timer);
          });

          if (ctx.options.callbacks.onDropdownOut) {
            ctx.options.callbacks.onDropdownOut.call(this, ctx);
          }
          clearTimeout(timer);

          timer = setTimeout($.proxy(ctx.dropdownUnfocus, this, ctx), ctx.options.focusOnHoverTimeout);
        }
        return this;
      };


      /**
       * Removes a focus from submenu
       * @protected
       */

      RDNavbar.prototype.dropdownUnfocus = function(ctx) {
        var $this;
        $this = $(this);
        $this.find('li.focus').add(this).removeClass('focus');
        return this;
      };


      /**
       * Closes submenu
       * @protected
       */

      RDNavbar.prototype.dropdownClose = function(ctx, e) {
        var $this;
        if (e.target !== this && !$(e.target).parents('.rd-navbar-submenu').length) {
          $this = $(this);
          $this.find('li.focus').add(this).removeClass('focus').removeClass('opened');
          if (ctx.options.callbacks.onDropdownClose) {
            ctx.options.callbacks.onDropdownClose.call(this, ctx);
          }
        }
        return this;
      };


      /**
       * Toggles submenu popup to be shown on trigger click
       * @protected
       */

      RDNavbar.prototype.dropdownToggle = function(ctx) {
        $(this).toggleClass('opened').siblings().removeClass('opened');
        if (ctx.options.callbacks.onDropdownToggle) {
          ctx.options.callbacks.onDropdownToggle.call(this, ctx);
        }
        return this;
      };


      /**
       * Scrolls the page to triggered anchor
       * @protected
       */

      RDNavbar.prototype.goToAnchor = function(ctx, e) {
        var $anchor, hash;
        hash = this.hash;
        $anchor = $(hash);

        if (!ctx.getOption('anchorNav')){
          return false;
        }

        if ($anchor.length) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $anchor.offset().top + ctx.getOption('anchorNavOffset') + 1
          }, ctx.getOption('anchorNavSpeed'), ctx.getOption('anchorNavEasing'), function() {
            return ctx.changeAnchor(hash);
          });
        }
        return this;
      };


      /**
       * Highlight an active anchor
       * @protected
       */

      RDNavbar.prototype.activateAnchor = function(e) {
        var $anchor, $item, $link, ctx, docHeight, hash, i, link, links, navOffset, scrollTop, winHeight;
        ctx = this;
        scrollTop = ctx.$doc.scrollTop();
        winHeight = ctx.$win.height();
        docHeight = ctx.$doc.height();
        navOffset = ctx.getOption('anchorNavOffset');

        if (!ctx.options.anchorNav){
          return false;
        }

        if (scrollTop + winHeight > docHeight - 50) {
          $anchor = $('[data-type="anchor"]').last();
          if ($anchor.length) {
            if ($anchor.offset().top >= scrollTop) {
              hash = '#' + $anchor.attr("id");
              $item = $('.rd-navbar-nav a[href^="' + hash + '"]').parent();
              if (!$item.hasClass('active')) {
                $item.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                if (ctx.options.callbacks.onAnchorChange) {
                  ctx.options.callbacks.onAnchorChange.call($anchor[0], ctx);
                }
              }
            }
          }
          return $anchor;
        } else {
          links = $('.rd-navbar-nav a[href^="#"]').get();
          for (i in links) {
            link = links[i];
            $link = $(link);
            hash = $link.attr('href');
            $anchor = $(hash);
            if ($anchor.length) {
              if ($anchor.offset().top + navOffset <= scrollTop && $anchor.offset().top + $anchor.outerHeight() > scrollTop) {
                $link.parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                if (ctx.options.callbacks.onAnchorChange) {
                  ctx.options.callbacks.onAnchorChange.call($anchor[0], ctx);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        return null;
      };


      /**
       * Returns current anchor
       * @protected
       */

      RDNavbar.prototype.getAnchor = function() {
        if (history) {
          if (history.state) {
            return history.state.id;
          }
        }
        return null;
      };


      /**
       * Changes current page anchor
       * @protected
       */

      RDNavbar.prototype.changeAnchor = function(hash) {
        if (history) {
          if (history.state) {
            if (history.state.id !== hash) {
              history.replaceState({
                'anchorId': hash
              }, null, hash);
            } else {
              history.pushState({
                'anchorId': hash
              }, null, hash);
            }
          } else {
            history.pushState({
              'anchorId': hash
            }, null, hash);
          }
        }
        return this;
      };


      /**
       * Applies all JS event handlers
       * @protected
       */

      RDNavbar.prototype.applyHandlers = function(ctx) {
        if (ctx.options.responsive != null) {
          ctx.$win.on('resize.navbar', $.proxy(ctx.resize, ctx.$win[0], ctx)).on('resize.navbar', $.proxy(ctx.resizeWrap, ctx)).on('resize.navbar', $.proxy(ctx.stickUp, (ctx.$clone != null ? ctx.$clone : ctx.$element), ctx)).on('orientationchange.navbar', $.proxy(ctx.resize, ctx.$win[0], ctx)).trigger('resize.navbar');
        }
        ctx.$doc.on('scroll.navbar', $.proxy(ctx.stickUp, (ctx.$clone != null ? ctx.$clone : ctx.$element), ctx)).on('scroll.navbar', $.proxy(ctx.activateAnchor, ctx));
        ctx.$element.add(ctx.$clone).find('[data-rd-navbar-toggle]').each(function() {
          var $this;
          $this = $(this);
          $this.on('click', $.proxy(ctx.switchToggle, this, ctx));
          return $this.parents('body').on('click', $.proxy(ctx.closeToggle, this, ctx));
        });
        ctx.$element.add(ctx.$clone).find('.rd-navbar-submenu').each(function() {
          var $this, timer;
          $this = $(this);
          timer = $this.parents(".rd-navbar--is-clone").length ? ctx.cloneTimer : ctx.focusTimer;
          $this.on('mouseleave.navbar', $.proxy(ctx.dropdownOut, this, ctx, timer));
          $this.find('> a').on('mouseenter.navbar', $.proxy(ctx.dropdownOver, this, ctx, timer));
          $this.find('> a').on('touchstart.navbar', $.proxy(ctx.dropdownTouch, this, ctx, timer));
          $this.find('> .rd-navbar-submenu-toggle').on('click', $.proxy(ctx.dropdownToggle, this, ctx));
          return $this.parents('body').on('click', $.proxy(ctx.dropdownClose, this, ctx));
        });
        ctx.$element.add(ctx.$clone).find('.rd-navbar-nav a[href^="#"]').each(function() {
          return $(this).on('click', $.proxy(ctx.goToAnchor, this, ctx));
        });

        ctx.$element.find('.rd-navbar-dropdown, .rd-navbar-megamenu').each(function() {
          var $this, rect;
          $this = $(this);
          rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
          if ((rect.left + $this.outerWidth()) >= window.innerWidth - 10) {
            this.className += ' rd-navbar-open-left';
          } else if ((rect.left - $this.outerWidth()) <= 10) {
            this.className += ' rd-navbar-open-right';
          }
        });

        return ctx;
      };


      /**
       * Switches classes of elements without transition
       * @protected
       */

      RDNavbar.prototype.switchClass = function(element, before, after) {
        var obj;
        obj = element instanceof jQuery ? element : $(element);
        obj.addClass('rd-navbar--no-transition').removeClass(before).addClass(after);
        obj[0].offsetHeight;
        return obj.removeClass('rd-navbar--no-transition');
      };


      /**
       * Gets specific option of plugin
       * @protected
       */

      RDNavbar.prototype.getOption = function(key) {
        var point, targetPoint;
        for (point in this.options.responsive) {
          if (point <= window.innerWidth) {
            targetPoint = point;
          }
        }
        if ((this.options.responsive != null) && (this.options.responsive[targetPoint][key] != null)) {
          return this.options.responsive[targetPoint][key];
        } else {
          return this.options[key];
        }
      };


      /**
       * Add additional class to navbar toggles to identify it when navbar is cloned
       * @protected
       */

      RDNavbar.prototype.addAdditionalClassToToggles = function(navbarClass, toggleAdditionalClass, toggleElAdditionalClass) {
        return $(navbarClass).find('[data-rd-navbar-toggle]').each(function() {
          var toggleElement;
          $(this).addClass(toggleAdditionalClass);
          toggleElement = this.getAttribute('data-rd-navbar-toggle');
          return $(this).parents('body').find(navbarClass).find(toggleElement).addClass(toggleElAdditionalClass);
        });
      };

      return RDNavbar;

    })();

    /**
     * The jQuery Plugin for the RD Navbar
     * @public
     */
    $.fn.extend({
      RDNavbar: function(options) {
        var $this;
        $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.data('RDNavbar')) {
          return $this.data('RDNavbar', new RDNavbar(this, options));
        }
      }

      /**
       * RD Navbar window export
       * @public
       */
    });
    return window.RDNavbar = RDNavbar;
  })(window.jQuery, document, window);


  /**
   * The Plugin AMD export
   * @public
   */

  console.log(typeof module !== "undefined" && module !== null)
  if (typeof module !== "undefined" && module !== null) {
    module.exports = window.RDNavbar;
  } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(["jquery"], function() {
      'use strict';
      return window.RDNavbar;
    });
  }
}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still encountering this error, try using export default instead of module.exports inside your .Vue file where you import the module. I got the same error and this fixed it. See this [module.exports vs. export default in Node.js and ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294870/module-exports-vs-export-default-in-node-js-and-es6) and this https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039#issuecomment-273804003