# How can I add the commonjs module to a Nuxt project?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I'm new to javascript and I am following a Nuxt tutorial where I created the app skeleton with `npx create-nuxt-app`. The tutorial got me up and running with a basic frontend. Now I need to add the module `commonjs` to my project (to resolve Error: exports is read-only when I try to `require` modules from a nodejs backend).

I was told I could add commonjs to babel.config.js as shown below. However, my Nuxt project does not have babel.config.js.

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@vue/app', {"modules": "commonjs"}]
  ]
}
```

I tried adding `commonjs` to the modules array in nuxt.config.js and that results in new errors, so I removed it. (After reading the [Nuxt docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/configuration), I see that the modules section is for *Nuxt.js modules*.)

**How can I add the commonjs module to a Nuxt project** created with npx create-nuxt-app?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40295288/10992294

Comment: What you mean by add?