# How to import and use function in another function in JS

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, mean

I have a main file 'index.js' and I want to import and use the functions in it in another js file.

I tried importing the file using require but it did not work.Can someone help me with suggestion.

Index.js,

```
   function dcLib() {
       function test() {
          console.log('Hi');
       }
       return {
          test:test
       }
  };
   export default dcLib;
```

column.js,

```
   const dcLib = require('../index');
   dcLib.test()
```

The above code giving error as

```
      TypeError: dcLib.test is not a function
```

Comment: `function dcLib {` - that's invalid syntax - you need `function dcLib() {` and then when you do `dcLib.test()` you still need to execute the function - `dcLib().test()`

Comment: Function `dcLib` is a function which *when called* returns an object which has a property which is a function. You never call `dcLib`, and it doesn't have a `test` property by itself.

Comment: @VLAZ Sory for the typo,edited it.I tried like you said still showing error as dcLib().test()   --->dcLib is not a function

Comment: deceze what should be the solution

Comment: @pleasent it largely depends on which transpiler you're using. Default exports changes their import behavior according to many things. In your case, you should probably do `dcLib.default().test()`. If you want that kind of require, you should export an unnamed function instead. You can play around here, if you want to : https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-3wwz8a

Comment: @briosheje,it worked like a charm.Thanks a lot and why do i need to keep default() as i ket it in index.js?.

Comment: @pleasent this is how "require" works. You should instead use `import dcLib from './index'` in order to access the default export properly. I've edited the above example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-3wwz8a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either do:

```
const dcLib = require('../index');
dcLib.default().test();
```

... or, if you prefere it, you can do:

```
const dcLib = require('../index').default;
dcLib().test();
```

Or, in a simpler (ES6) fashion, just do:

```
import dcLib from './test';
dcLib().test();
```

ES6 imports and exports behaves differently if you're using `require` instead of `import`. Also, things changes a bit according to the environment and, eventually, the transpiler, if any is used. Read more about that [here, where Felix Kling made a pretty exhaustive overview about such argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40295288/2275797)

As mentioned in the comment, I've made a working example to play with on stackblitz, feel free to play around with it with both cases: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-3wwz8a?file=index.js