# New to node.js; need help importing an npm module into my front-end vanilla JS project

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, import, node-modules

Let me preface this by admitting that I'm very new to node.js and web development as a whole. I've been combing through stackoverflow and google searches for a solution, but to no avail. Mainly, I am unsure of which steps I need to take since this is my first time dabbling in the use of npm modules.

Basically, I created a static website for my friend that allows users to add their own puns to a preexisting array of puns inspired by her cats' names. The site then randomizes the array if users want to view the puns one at a time. For the submissions, I've already set limits that users must write something between 0-50 characters that contains at least one of the names of her cats. **The functionality of the site was coded in vanilla JS**. However, the program does not yet account for **gibberish submissions** that otherwise meet the above requirements (e.g., "alksdjjsd *Cat name* slkjsd"). That is the last step that will finalize the website.

**To fix this, I would like to add [this npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asdfjkl) to my project.** I tested the module, and it was able to correctly separate gibberish submissions from the non-gibberish submissions in my array. **The only problem is, I have no clue how to proceed.**

Naturally, I installed the package in node and then copy/pasted the import statement - per the [usage instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asdfjkl#usage) - straight into my .js file, but then I figured out that the package won't run in the browser. So then I installed node.js and created a package.json with the following dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^16.5.0",
    "watchify": "^3.11.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "asdfjkl": "0.0.6"
  }
```

As you might have guessed, I also created a bundle.js file that I have linked in a script tag in my index.html file `<script src="bundle.js"></script>`
 with the following also in my package.json file:

```
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "browserify index.js -o bundle.js",
    "watch": "watchify index.js -o bundle.js"
  },
```

However, it's still unclear to me how I ought to follow the usage instructions in the npm module. **I'm unable to use the suggested import statement:**

```
import asdfjkl from 'asdfjkl';
```

in my code (index.js/bundle.js files) without seeing **errors in my terminal** such as "*ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'*" or

```
import asdfjkl from 'asdfjkl';
       ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I noticed that a lot of people with this similar problem are using tools like Babel, Gulp, and other packages, but I can't tell which tools I might need, and I definitely don't understand how to use them.

Any guidance on how to include this package into my front-end project would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!

---

## Edit: The Solution

---

In order for the function `asdfjkl()` to work, I ended up needing to write

```
var asdfjkl = require('asdfjkl').default;
```

For others with this issue needing clarification, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40295288/11714779) to be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import and Export are features from ECMAScript 6 (http://es6-features.org/#ValueExportImport), so i guess you are not using any Javascript compiler ( Babel for example https://babeljs.io/docs/en/ ).
But, if you don't want use any compiler you can simple change the code to import the library like this:

```
var asdfjkl = require('asdfjkl');
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I just tried the `var asdfjkl = require('asdfjkl');` code as you suggested, and received this error in the terminal:
`console.log(asdfjkl('hello'));`
`TypeError: asdfjkl is not a function`

as well as `Uncaught ReferenceError: asdfjkl is not defined` in the browser. I'm not sure why.



If it turns out that Babel is the way to go, are there any particular packages you would recommend for this specific project? I realize there are so many different packages related to Babel, it's a bit intimidating

Comment: Looks strange to me that doesn't work, i saw you use browserify and look the first example (http://browserify.org/#install), let's try to build it again.
Anyway here you can find a good example how to play a bit with babel with vanilla app https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/introduction-to-babel-and-javascript-bundlers-fe6165de197c

Comment: Thanks for the links! I'll go ahead and give them a thorough read, get some sleep, play around with the code a bit tomorrow. I'll let you know of any changes

Comment: I figured it out by tinkering with different import statements in the package's runkit.js and test.js files. For some reason, this line of code did the trick:
`var asdfjkl = require('asdfjkl').default;`

Answer (score 0):

You can install an npm package using,
npm install  --save

ex: npm install asdfjkl --save

Comment: Thanks for your response! I should have wrote that that was the first step I took. First I installed the package like so: "npm install asdfjkl --save" and then I tried using the import statement as suggested in the link, but it wasn't working for me.

Comment: Can you find the installed package inside your node_modules folder?

Comment: Yes. I've also tried to import asdfjkl from the path file ('node_modules/asdfjkl/lib/asdfjkl.js' ... or something to that effect) but no luck