# How to include classes from seperate file in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, import, export, require

I currently have a `hero.js` file in a directory, and it looks like this

```
let Person = class PersonClass {
    constructor(name) {

        ...

class Hero {
    constructor(name, level) {

        ...

class Mage extends Hero {
    constructor(name, level, spell) {

        ...
```

Then in another file, I want to use these classes.

So I have:

```
require("./hero");

const manny = new Hero("Manny", 12);
const george = new Person("George");
```

and neither george nor manny work, they both throw `Reference Error: Person/Hero is not defined`.

When I have the Person or Hero class code in the file above george and manny, they do work properly.

I want to know how to move class definitions to another file and `require` them in another file.

Comment: What environment: browser or something like node? In a browser you just need to make sure the hero script is included in the page before the other script, and the classes defined globally or some accessible scope. No need for require.

Comment: Try looking at different syntaxes (CommonJS vs ES6) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294870/module-exports-vs-export-default-in-node-js-and-es6

Answer (score -1):

It's very straightforward. you should use `export`

```
let Person = class PersonClass {
    constructor(name) {

        ...

class Hero {
    constructor(name, level) {

        ...

class Mage extends Hero {
    constructor(name, level, spell) {


export const Person
export const Hero
export const Mage
```

And in another file,

```
import {Person, Hero, Mage} from './hero'
```

Comment: Giorgi, I tried just dropping your suggestion in and ran into a problem


```
import {Person, Hero, Mage} from './hero'
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```