# module.exports and export default in nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, nuxt.js

In the past days I have kind of a headache with this and it's surely due to my lack of experience. I recently started using `nuxt` and `nuxt` modules.

As I use the command `yarn create nuxt-app my-project`, the `nuxt.config.js` file is populated with `module.exports`. My problem is that when I was installing certain modules, the configuration was only working in `export default`. I have for example the following config:

```
  build: {
      extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      if (isDev && isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

This configuration only works inside `export default` but not when I write it in `module.exports`, I have no clue about the reason.

Another example is with `head`, let's say the following code:

```
  head: {
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.png' }
    ]
  },
```

When I put it  in `export default`, it doesn't work, and in `module.exports` it works. So, until now I'm doing trial and error depending where it works.

I know that there is a reference in the question [module.exports vs. export default in Node.js and ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294870/module-exports-vs-export-default-in-node-js-and-es6) . However it's not yet clear to me why some stuff work in `module.exports` and some other stuff in `export default`.

Some explanation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify how exactly it didn't work? What was the error message? The difference between `export` and `module.exports` in *transpiled* environment is determined how ES/CommonJS module interoperation works (depends on Webpack/Babel/TS config). In user land, `module.exports` is usually interchangeable with `export default` because CommonJS module exports are treated as default exports. In some configs `module.exports` is interchangeable with `export { }`. I can't check how module interop works in Nuxt configs. Try `exports.default = ` instead of `module.exports`, let me know if this works.

Comment: In my case, [nuxt.config.ts] does not load the configuration under the conditions of [export default config] and [exports.default = config].

Answer (score -1):

I'm having a similar problem... trying to effect 'disable Nuxt/no-cjs-in-config for this line' in order to be able to use `module.exports =` but it keep reverting back to `export default` when I run `firebase deploy --only functions` in my terminal and throwing syntaxError

Comment: From Review: Hi, "I'm having this problem too" cannot be considered an answer in S.O. rules. Please post this as a comment to the question.