# Import class from Node.js in normal JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, export

I have files that use the Node.js framework and other files that I want to implement without using that. 
When I try to import a class from my node files, where I used module.exports, to my js files, i get the error that "the requested module does not provide an export named default". 
So is there any way for me to import the node.js class in my JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think only in two methods for solved your problem

**METHOD 1**

Module1.js

```
class HelloWorld {
  getHelloWorld() {
    return 'Hello World';
  }
}

module.exports = HelloWorld
```

Module2.js

```
const HelloWorld = require('./module1.js');
const helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
```

**METHOD 2** ***Node <= v12*** (Extension file: `.msj` and run it like `node --experimental-modules module2.mjs`)

module1.mjs

```
export default class HelloWorld {
    getHelloWorld() {
        return 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

module2.msj

```
import HelloWorld from './module1.mjs';
const helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
console.log(helloWorld.getHelloWorld());
```

**METHOD 2** ***Node >= v13*** (Extension files: `.msj` or Add `{ "type": "module" }` in the `package.json`)

module1.mjs or module1.js if you add `{ "type": "module" }` in the `package.json`

```
export default class HelloWorld {
    getHelloWorld() {
        return 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

module2.mjs or module2.js if you add `{ "type": "module" }` in the `package.json`

```
import HelloWorld from './module1.mjs';
const helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
console.log(helloWorld.getHelloWorld());
```

NOTE: If you are interested in knowing the difference between "module.exports vs export default", this topic can help you [module.exports vs. export default in Node.js and ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294870/module-exports-vs-export-default-in-node-js-and-es6)