# JavaScript export vs module.exports in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

Can somebody help me understand the differences between javascript class/function export and module.exports in node JS and why there are two ways to export javascript attributes and functions and when to use which export. Also is it possible to use both the exports together?

```
export function getUsers() {
    return users
}
```

VS

```
module.exports = {
  getUsers: function () {
    return users
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide code snippets of the two implementations you're referring to?

Comment: @m_callens Sure. I've edited the question with code snippets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [module.exports vs. export default in Node.js and ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294870/module-exports-vs-export-default-in-node-js-and-es6)