# How do i make an export dafault in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

this is my server.js file to import http from http module. i need to make my server.js file a module and import it in the index.js file which is the  entry to my app.

```
   import { createServer } from 'http'; 
   function start(){
       function onRequest(req,res){
           console.log("Request recieved");
           res.writeHead(200, {"content-type":"text/plain"});
           res.write("Good afternoon Paullaster");
           res.end();
       }

       createServer(onRequest).listen(8080);
       console.log("Response ready");
   }

   export { start};
```

this is my index.js file that should be the entry point to my application

```
import server from "./server";
server.start()
```

i get this error

```
PS C:\Users\paullaster-geek\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Dive node> node -r esm index.js
C:\Users\paullaster-geek\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Dive node\index.js:1
SyntaxError: The requested module 'file:///C:/Users/paullaster- 
geek/OneDrive/Desktop/Projects/Dive%20node/server.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
PS C:\Users\paullaster-geek\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Dive node>
```

i have added an esm to my project

```
//npm init esm
```

and

```
 npm i esm
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import { start } from "./server";
start()
```

or see more about here
[module.exports vs. export default in Node.js and ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294870/module-exports-vs-export-default-in-node-js-and-es6)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write `server.start()`, I would recommend

```
import * as server from "./server";
```

but @StanimirGeorgiev's suggestion is fine as well.