# How to export from within an imported module's Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, es6-modules

I'm trying to work around the fact that I need to import a [pure ESM package](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c) into a non-module. I can't change that fact about [the script](https://gridsome.org/docs/config/).

The workaround I'm trying to use is the `import()` function (a "[dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports)"). That returns a Promise instead of the actual module. I can't use `await` since I'm not in a module, so instead I'm using `.then()`.

The pure ESM package ([unist-util-visit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unist-util-visit)) is used in a function exported by my script, which is then used in another script. So the import chain goes:

`importer.js` imports `imported.js` imports `unist-util-visit`

So the issue is that anything I export from within the `.then()` function in `imported.js` does not show up in `importer.js`.

And it's not even a timing issue. I used an `EventEmitter` to make `importer.js` wait until `imported.js`'s `.then()` is done executing:

`imported.js`:

```js
const EventEmitter = require('events');

module.exports.emitter = new EventEmitter();
module.exports.outsideFxn = function () {
  console.log('hello');
}
import('unist-util-visit').then((unistUtilVisit) => {
  module.exports.fxn = function() {
    console.log(`unistUtilVisit: ${typeof unistUtilVisit}`);
  }
  module.exports.emitter.emit('ready');
});
```

`importer.js`:

```js
import('./imported.js').then((imported) => {
  console.log("In importer.js's .then():");
  console.log('  fxn:', imported.fxn);
  console.log('  outsideFxn:', imported.outsideFxn);
  imported.emitter.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("After imported.js is done:")
    console.log('  fxn:', imported.fxn);
  });
});
```

When I execute it, this is the output:

```
$ node importer.js 
In importer.js's .then():
  fxn: undefined
  outsideFxn: [Function (anonymous)]
After imported.js is done:
  fxn: undefined
```

What am I missing? Why are no exports being defined in the `.then()` function? How can I get my function exported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead  of

```
import('unist-util-visit').then((unistUtilVisit) => {
  module.exports.fxn = function() {
    console.log(`unistUtilVisit: ${typeof unistUtilVisit}`);
  }
  module.exports.emitter.emit('ready');
});
```

where you attempt to modify your module's `exports` after it has probably been consumed by dependents, why not export a promise that yields the function when it completes?

```
module.exports.fxnP = 
    import('unist-util-visit')
      .then((unistUtilVisit) => () => { 
          console.log(`unistUtilVisit: ${typeof unistUtilVisit}`); 
      });
```

Now you consume it:

```
import('./imported.js').then((imported) => {
    imported.fxnP.then((fxn) => {
        fxn();
    });
});
```

or, more neatly::

```
import('./imported.js')
    .then(({fxnP}) => fxnP)
    .then((fxn) => fxn());
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you! It works, though I'm not sure why. I really need to get a better handle on Promises.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom `require` hook like [jiti](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jiti) which can do exactly what you want synchronously.

Without hooking `require`:

```js
$ node test.cjs

// test.cjs
const jiti = require('jiti')();
const unistUtilVisit = jiti("unist-util-visit");
```

Hooking `require` programmatically:

```js
$ node test.cjs

// test.cjs
require('jiti')().register();
const unistUtilVisit = require("unist-util-visit");
```

Hooking `require` through a command line option:

```js
$ node -r jiti/register test.cjs

// test.cjs
const unistUtilVisit = require("unist-util-visit");
```

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. So it looks like it transpiles the imported module and its dependencies to convert them to CommonJS? Are there any compatibility issues with this?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, everything should just work! It's a direct translation.

Comment: Okay I found my first incompatibility! My module exported a function as default, and when `jiti` imports it, instead of the result being the function, it's an object whose `default` key is the function.

Comment: No, that's intended behavior for compatibility reasons. I would consider ot a bug if it didn't do that. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40295288/12375929