# Type declaration file doesn't work with commonjs module syntax

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-declaration

Today I was writing a type declaration file for a JavaScript file but despite my hours of trying I couldn't make it work inside a node application. Then I tried switching to es6 module syntax and surprisingly it worked.

Then I discovered that I can also make it work with commonjs module syntax if I add `".default"` before accessing any properties of that module. For example I've to use `person.default.name` instead of `person.name` to get the intellisence.

I wrote a small module to demonstrate the problem. I've created an object with identical typings of my actual module.

**index.js**

```js
const names = {
  firstname: "Alex",
  middlename: "Blex",
  lastname: "Clex",
};

const state = {
  isAlive() {
    return true;
  },
  isWalking() {
    return false;
  },
};

function talk(speech) {
  console.log(speech);
}

const person = {
  names,
  state,
  talk
};

module.exports = person;
```

**index.d.ts**

```js
declare type predicate = (v: unknown) => boolean;
declare function talk(speech: string): void;

declare const person: {
  names: {
    [key: string]: string;
  };
  state: {
    [key: string]: predicate;
  };
  talk: typeof talk;
};

export default person;
```

**test1.js**

```js
const person = require("./index");

const isAlive = person.default.state.isAlive();
//---------------------^^^^^^^----------------
// The above line throws an error as expected.
// I've to use "person.default.whatever" to get intellisence
// In the editor it shows "typeof isAlive = boolean".

const isReallyAlive = person.state.isAlive();
// EditorError: Property 'state' does not exist on type
// 'typeof import(./index.js)'.

// In the editor it shows typeof "isReallyAlive = any"
// But infact isReallyAlive is boolean.
```

**test2.js**

Using es6 module syntax it works perfectly.

[image: Using es6 module syntax]

I'm fairly new to Typescript so kindly give me some hint where I'm making the mistake.
Thanks in advance, I highly appreciate your time on `StackOverflow` <3.

Comment: What about just using `person.state`? `default` is normally only used for ESM not CommonJS

Comment: With commonjs module the editor says `person.state` is not defined but if I console.log `person.state` it indeed prints the state object.

Comment: I'm assuming the real file is much more complicated than that, because otherwise it would be really simple to just convert it to ts lol

Comment: If I do `const person = require("./index");` person is `any` for me. Do you have any special tsconfig? I used a fresh project with `npx tsc --init`.

Comment: @Elias I don't have any special flags enabled in my tsconfig and before posting the question here I've tried using typescript. But even if I use typescript I'm concerned that those who will use my library in their Node application will not get intellisence as most of them will be using commonjs module syntax.

Comment: I think you would actually need to do `import person = require("./index");` inside typescript, and not const. Also, the default level is correct.

Comment: No typescript should generate the correct output for commonjs requires.

Comment: I just tried replacing `const` with `import` and I got greeted by Nodejs with `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237465/discussion-between-elias-and-h-sifat).

Answer (score 1):

So as explained by this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/40295288/10315665 the `export default` option only creates a `default` key inside of the `exports` object. That's why you can still have normal exports besides it.

> Many people consider module.exports = ... to be equivalent to export default ... and exports.foo ... to be equivalent to export const foo = .... That's not quite true though, or at least not how Babel does it.

So your definition file is wrong. It should be:

```js
declare type predicate = (v: unknown) => boolean;

export declare const names: {
    [key: string]: string;
};

export declare const state: {
    [key: string]: predicate;
};

export declare function talk(speech: string): void;
```

And if you respect that, you can actually utilize typescript and it's awesome type checking by simply writing typescript in the first place!:

```
export const names = {
  firstname: "Alex",
  middlename: "Blex",
  lastname: "Clex",
};

export const state = {
  isAlive() {
    return true;
  },
  isWalking() {
    return false;
  },
};

export function talk(speech: string) {
  console.log(speech);
}
```

Just remember to enable `"declaration": true` in the `tsconfig` to also generate declaration files .

Comment: I just sort of "re-learnt" this, so yay for me :D

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I tried your solution with both nvim and vscode but sadly it didn't work. I still have to use `.default`. But I don't wanna waste your time anymore for this question. Lemme switch back to typescript. Thank you so much for giving me your valuable time <3 .

Comment: @h-sifat If you use the definition file I've provided it **should** work. Have you tried running `npx tsc --noemit` instead of just checking the editor? That should give you the real deal. Also, try the `> Typescript: Restart TS Server`  command in vs code to clear any caching issues.

Comment: And you are not wasting my time, if I didn't feel like answering questions I would simply not open this website.

Comment: if you are trying to import this from typescript now, you would have to do `import * as person from "./person";`

Comment: Or try providing a key `default` in the `exports` (in JS) object and add an `export default` statement inside the d.ts file. I've not tested this but in theory...

Comment: Elias both of our declaration file  works with typescript and es6 modules. But commonjs is the troublemaker here. I've tried writing my module with typescript and generate declaration file by the compiler but I still have to use `.default` with commonjs module syntax. Why life has to be so complicated :'( ?!

Comment: @h-sifat can you like make a repo that I can download and test against it? And most of the time these things are difficult because you are either doing something very niche, or your doing it wrong, lol :D

Comment: Currently I'm learning typescript. I'll need some time to finish this course. I'm hoping that after taking this course I'll be able to fix the problem myself otherwise I'll give you a knock :) .