# Unable to import module in nodejs using ES6 Modules

Tags: node.js, nodes, node-modules, es6-modules

I have just started learning Node.js and i was trying to connect my application to MongoDB database.
Here ***Server.js*** is my main file with just two line

```
import { connectMongoDB } from "./config/db";
connectMongoDB();
```

and i was trying to import my function connectMongoDB from file db.js, here is the content of db.js

```
import config from "config";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const mongoDBUri = config.get("mongoDBUri");
export const connectMongoDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(mongoDBUri, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    });
    console.log("MongoDB connected");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(
      "[Error] MongoDB did not get connected due to issue " + error.message
    );
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
```

location of file seems correct to me
[image]

I tried using require instead of import and it worked fine.
Error thrown -

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\bisht\Project\DHH\dhh\config\db' imported from C:\Users\bisht\Project\DHH\dhh\server.js
[0] Did you mean to import ../config/db.js?
[0]     at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:259:11)
[0]     at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:636:10)
[0]     at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:726:11)
[0]     at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:97:40)
[0]     at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:243:28)
[0]     at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:47:40)
[0]     at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:46:36) {
[0]   code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
```

Comment: What version of Node.js are you using? Can you show us the package.json file?

Comment: Hi @TsvetanGanev, currently i am using v12.18.3, should i update this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i went through the documentation of Node and found out that when we are using ES6 to import modules then we need to define our file with extension ".mjs" instead of just ".js" and while importing the function i also mentioned the extension like this -
`import { connectMongoDB } from "./config/db.mjs";` and it worked fine

Comment: Thanks. In my case JS extension works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running that function in an async context?

For instance:

```js
import { connectMongoDB } from "./config/db";
    
(async () => {
    await connectMongoDB();
})();
```

Comment: i tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `module.exports` and `export` take a look at:   [module.exports vs. export default in Node.js and ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294870/module-exports-vs-export-default-in-node-js-and-es6)
At your db.js file, try to change the function exporting as below:

```
exports.connectMongoDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(mongoDBUri, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    });
    console.log("MongoDB connected");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(
      "[Error] MongoDB did not get connected due to issue " + error.message
    );
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the link but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

By default, Node JS uses modules according to the CommonJS standard. import - is an ES6 standard. You need to configure package.json for ES6 operation. Add a pair: `"type": "module".`
example:

```
{
  "name": "index.js",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```