# Shopify API Node/Express Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Rest')

Tags: node.js, express, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

Just starting off with Shopify, and trying to get an order. Following the Shopify API documentation, here is my code:

```
const Shopify = require('@shopify/shopify-api');

const client = new Shopify.Clients.Rest('my-store.myshopify.com', 
process.env.SHOPIFY_KEY);

module.exports.getShopifyOrderById = async (orderId) => {
return await client.get({ 
    path: `orders/${orderId}`,
  });
}
```

I get the following error when I execute this code:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Rest')`

Can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use Object destructing to get the Shopify object or use default export like below.

```
const { Shopify } = require('@shopify/shopify-api');

const client = new Shopify.Clients.Rest('my-store.myshopify.com', 
process.env.SHOPIFY_KEY);
```

OR

```
const Shopify = require('@shopify/shopify-api').default;

const client = new Shopify.Clients.Rest('my-store.myshopify.com', 
process.env.SHOPIFY_KEY);
```

OR

```
const ShopifyLib = require('@shopify/shopify-api');

const client = new ShopifyLib.Shopify.Clients.Rest('my-store.myshopify.com', 
process.env.SHOPIFY_KEY);
```

This has to do with how ES6 modules are emulated in CommonJS and how you import the module. You can [read about that here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40295288/2803788).

Comment: It's incredible how difficult is to find this information on official Shopify docs. There is almost no mention of this line: `const { Shopify } = require('@shopify/shopify-api');`