# How do I use ESmodule imports with hardhat (that uses CommonJS)?

Tags: javascript, hardhat, javascript-import

The [hardhat testing tutorial](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/testing-contracts.html) uses `require` for imports, and not `import`.

[This site](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/) describes CommonJS using `require` and ESModule as using `import`.

I have some code that uses `ESModule` style (exports and imports), and I can't easily use it in Hardhat code.

**How do I use the ESModule-style code in hardhat?**

When running `npx hardhat test`

- If I use ESModule style `import` in the hardhat code, I get the error you would expect:

```
An unexpected error occurred:

.../solidity/test/some_code.js:6
import { aSymbol } from "../blah/src/utils/helpers"
^^^^^^
```

- If I use `require` in the hardhat code, I get complaints you'd expect about the ESModule style `export`:

```
.../blah/src/utils/helpers.js:35
export async function aSymbol() {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../solidity/test/some_code.js:5:6)
```

**EDIT**: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40295288) may be related, still reading.

Comment: Oh, maybe I can use this awful-looking "Universal Module Definition": https://riptutorial.com/javascript/example/16339/universal-module-definition--umd-

Comment: UMD is old technology that was meant to support Node/CommonJS modules in browsers (think webpack/browserify). It does not support ESM imports (at least not if you're writing it yourself). You can of course use something like webpack to "compile" your ESM files into UMD (webpack) modules which you can then require.

Comment: How do I do this exactly? It appears involved, and I don't see examples out there.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `esm` module.
First install it running `npm i --save-dev esm`.
Then add a hardhat script in your `package.json` file as follows:

```
"scripts": {
    "hardhat": "node --require esm node_modules/.bin/hardhat",
```

then use hardhat through `npm run hardhat` instead of `hardhat` command.

Comment: Doesn't work for `hardhat.config.ts`, see https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/957