# When I run my script, it outputs mml2tex is not a function

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts, runkit

When I run my code in RunKit, it outputs "TypeError: mml2tex is not a function" in the console.

Here's the link for the code: https://runkit.com/embed/4rnhdcgjrzwl

```
var mml2tex = require("mml2tex")
const mml = `
    <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
        <msqrt>
            <mn>2</mn>
        </msqrt>
    </math>
`;

const tex = mml2tex(mml);
console.log(tex);
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change the way you are importing the package.

```js
const mml2tex = require('mml2tex').default;
 
const mml = `<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
        <msqrt>
            <mn>2</mn>
        </msqrt>
    </math>
`;
const tex = mml2tex(mml);
console.log(tex);
```

notice the extra `.default` when using the commonjs method.
more information in this answer: [module.exports vs. export default in Node.js and ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294870/module-exports-vs-export-default-in-node-js-and-es6)