# I cannot create connector using "@walletconnect/client" and getting error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, blockchain, web3js

I used "@walletconnect/client" module to create wallet connector.
Here is my code:

```
const WalletConnect = require("@walletconnect/client");
const connector = new WalletConnect({ uri });
```

This makes an error in my project.

```
Error: WalletConnect is not a constructor
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because WalletConnect is default exported and default exports do not work as expected in commonjs. [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40295288/9943028)

You should try this instead:

```js
const WalletConnect = require("@walletconnect/client").default;
const connector = new WalletConnect({ uri });
```

Answer (score 0):

use this npm package and install it, then use the below command to use it

npm i @metamask/detect-provider

```
import detectEthereumProvider from '@metamask/detect-provider'

const provider = await detectEthereumProvider()

if (provider) {

  console.log('Ethereum successfully detected!')
  })
} else {
  console.error('Please install MetaMask!', error)
}
```