# I get this error: Textfield is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, cypress

I know that there are a lot of question in Stackoverflow about this error, but after read some of them (+-12 questions) I don't get nothing.

My context is that I'm trying to build a npm package (my first package); in this Package there are some class that help to write Cypress more easily.

This is one the clases I want to load throught a npm package:

```js
// node_modules/prueba-para-oskar/src/Helpers/Fields/TextField.js
class TextField {
  /**
   *
   * @param {string} value
   * @param {string} selector
   * @param {object} options
   */
  type(value, selector, options) {
    this[options.widget](value,selector);
  }

  /**
   *
   * @param {string} value
   * @param {string} selector
   */
  ckeditor(value, selector){
    cy.ckeditor(value, selector)
  }

  noCkeditor(value, selector){
    cy.get(selector).type(value);
  }
}

module.exports = TextField;
```

This is my package index.js

```js
// node_modules/prueba-para-oskar/src/index.js

const TextField = require('./Helpers/Fields/TextField');


module.exports = {
    TextField
}
```

And this is my cypress page object

```js
// cypress/e2e/pages/ArticlePage.js

// If I load the file as class that are in the same folder than Cypress
// (not mpn package) they works without problems.
import { Property } from "../../support/Helpers/lib/Property";
import { Submit } from "../../support/Helpers/lib/Submit";
import { FileField } from "../../support/Helpers/Fields/FileField";
import { TextAreaField } from "../../support/Helpers/Fields/TextAreaField";
// import { TextField } from "../../support/Helpers/Fields/TextField";

import { TextField } from "prueba-para-oskar";

export default class ArticlePage {
  article_path = "/node/add/article";
  tagInput = 'input[data-drupal-selector="edit-field-tags-target-id"]';
  submitButton = 'input[data-drupal-selector="edit-submit"]';

  constructor() {
    this.Property = new Property();
    this.FileField = new FileField();
    this.TextAreaField = new TextAreaField();
    this.TextField = new TextField();
    this.Submit = new Submit();
  }

  userCanAccesArticlePage() {
    cy.visit(this.article_path, { failOnStatusCode: true });
  }

  havePermissionsToSeeNodeAddArticle() {
    cy.location("pathname").should("eq", this.article_path);
  }

  clickSubmitButttom() {
    cy.get(this.submitButton).click();
  }
}
```

The error appears when I try to load TextField inside ArticlePage.js

Any idea how to load the class from the npm pagacke to the ObjecPage class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the answer for this question

[module.exports vs. export default in Node.js and ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294870/module-exports-vs-export-default-in-node-js-and-es6)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, Aleska, I have read the answer but I don't get it works.

I'm able to import the class from TextField.js to Index.js (npm package); but Whan I load the class in the PageObject it give me bacck this: `Cannot read properties of undefined`

I think that It's something I make wrong but I don't find what it's.

Answer (score 2):

In an npm package, generally the `index,js` is at the root of the package not in `/src`.

Try this way

```js
// node_modules/prueba-para-oskar/index.js

const TextField = require('./src/Helpers/Fields/TextField');


module.exports = {
    TextField
}
```

Also (alternativiely) try adding a `main` entry to `package.json`

For example look at `node_modules/core-util-is/package.json`

```js
{
  "name": "core-util-is",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "description": "The `util.is*` functions introduced in Node v0.12.",
  "main": "lib/util.js",
  "repository": {
  ...
```

so your package.json

```js
{
  "name": "prueba-para-oskar",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    ...
```

Comment: Hello, Fody:
part of my package.json: `"main": "src/index.js",`

Comment: It worked for me - I duplicated your files and folders, put in `node_modules` and import in same way. I added new method `sayHello()` to `class TextField` just to test it's functioning.

Answer (score 0):

After take a walk and read again the link from Aleksa Djukic I have resolved my problem in this way:

```js
// node_modules/prueba-para-oskar/src/index.js
module.exports.TextField = require('./Helpers/Fields/TextField');
```

```js
// cypress/e2e/pages/ArticlePage.js
// Instead of import I use require.
const TextField = require("prueba-para-oskar").TextField;
```

```js
// cypress/support/step_definitions/articlePage.js
// Instead of import I use require.
const ArticlePage = require('../../e2e/pages/ArticlePage');
// I have to inicialice the class
const articlePage = new ArticlePage();
```