# register component in vue,js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js

I am working on a project in .NET with MVC and Vue.js, at the moment of wanting to use the components I have to declare it as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

import example from './components/example.vue'
import equiposcrear from './components/equipos/crear.vue'
import equipos from './components/equipos/index.vue'
import cargardiesel from './components/equipos/cargarDiesel.vue'

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        example,
        equiposcrear,
        equipos,
        cargardiesel
    }
})
```

If i registered as `Vue.component('equipos', require('./components/equipos/index.vue'));`

At the moment i want to use   send the error that the component is not registered

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Equipos";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div id="app">
    <equipos></equipos>
</div>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: If you hit F12 in the browser, in the network tab can you see all the files are loading correctly? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Are you saying it works in the first example, but you want to use `require` instead of `import`?

Comment: yes, first example work fine, bur with Vue.Component not working

Comment: try `require('./components/equipos/index.vue').default`

Comment: it solved with .default, thank you so much!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correctly use ES6 "export default" with CommonJS "require"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35971042/how-to-correctly-use-es6-export-default-with-commonjs-require)

Answer (score 0):

A local component registration like you are doing has two parts. You need to specify **the tag-name, then the source**. Like this...

```
components: {
    'example': example,
    'equiposcrear' : equiposcrear,
    'equipos' : equipos,
    'cargardiesel' : cargardiesel
}
```

[Here's](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) the doc.

Comment: OP is using ES6, so it doesn't really matter if the object key has the same name as the imported variable.

Comment: yes, if i use import example from './components/example.vue' and load the component as  <equipos></equipos>  works well, but with Vue.component('example', require('./components/example.vue')); send the error component not register